# Linking error OpenCV only after using a -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 for adding Matkab code

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, opencv

I've managed to run the example in the openCV site showing an image in eclipse (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html)

I have another project in which i read some matrix from a mat file, when i try to merge the two, to show the images read from the mat file, these error are shown:

```
19:09:59 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project testMAT ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/testMAT.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/extern/include -I/usr/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/testMAT.d" -MT"src/testMAT.d" -o "src/testMAT.o" "../src/testMAT.cpp"
../src/testMAT.cpp: In function ‘int diagnose(const char*, const char*)’:
../src/testMAT.cpp:70:43: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("the size of c is %u\n", sizeof c);
                                           ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:78:10: warning: unused variable ‘mrows’ [-Wunused-variable]
   mwSize mrows = mxGetM(fPtr);
          ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:79:10: warning: unused variable ‘ncols’ [-Wunused-variable]
   mwSize ncols = mxGetN(fPtr);
          ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:38:16: warning: unused variable ‘dir’ [-Wunused-variable]
   const char **dir;
                ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:39:22: warning: unused variable ‘nome’ [-Wunused-variable]
   const char *name, *nome;
                      ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:40:9: warning: unused variable ‘ndir’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int   ndir;
         ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:41:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int   i;
         ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:57:10: warning: variable ‘nElements’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   mwSize nElements;       /* number of elements in array */
          ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:60:11: warning: unused variable ‘realPtr’ [-Wunused-variable]
   double *realPtr;        /* pointer to data */
           ^
../src/testMAT.cpp:61:10: warning: variable ‘total’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   double total;           /* value to calculate */
          ^
Finished building: ../src/testMAT.cpp

**Building target: testMAT
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o "testMAT"  ./src/testMAT.o   -leng -lmat -lmex -lut -lmx -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
makefile:45: recipe for target 'testMAT' failed
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testMAT] Error 1 **

19:10:00 Build Finished (took 810ms)
```

this errors are shown even on the opencv example when i only add the  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64, without adding any code to the source file.
Without the flag, everything works fine.

How can i include matlab code into this opencv project?

Comment: Looks like you have undefined references to libtiff functions in opencv_highgui. I think libtiff should have been provided and built with your OpenCV build. Check that you have it and that it is properly linked.

Comment: @Naveh  i don't understand why it all works fine without the - Wl flag and why it spits these errors with the flag, rpath should just add a search directory for linking purposes, not break existing link paths

Answer (score 0):

This topic is old but I had the same problem and I fixed it.

I tried to reinstall OpenCV, and I finally discovered with ccmake that

> BUILD_TIFF | OFF

is the defaut parameter when you install OpenCV.

So I put it to ON and reinstall OpenCV and it works.